# Getting the selected values in a checkbox list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have set up the following method when the checkbox list is checked.

```
 protected void chk1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem list in chk1.Items)
        {
            if (list.Selected)
            {
                string name = list.Value.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
```

I need to display the checked item from the checkbox list. However, for each iteration the selected attribute always comes false. It never satisfies the condition

```
                if (list.Selected)
                {
                    string name = list.Value.ToString();
                }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: how many items are checked? also `name` will be overwritten if you have more than `1` ListItem checked

Comment: There are 3 items in the list and I need to display the checked items.1 value is checked . Is there a way we can ensure that > 1 value is never checked. I do not want to use  a radio button

Comment: are you wanting to do the check each time you check or uncheck an item? `AutoPostBack` property on the control will also determine the behavior if you want to get the values after a button click for example then I would remove the code from the existing event handler and put that code in a separate method or inside of the button_Click event..

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the existing code where you are displaying the select item values as well you are assigning it to name but once you leave that method name is not accessible it's local to that eventhandler. you need to create a static variable that will hold the items that were selected. I hope that this makes sense to you..?  you need to show all relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var selectedListItems = chk1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected);
```

or in your case

```
var list = chk1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected);
```

now you will have a Collection that you can check / code against

also make sure that this code is being fired and or check if there is a `PostBack`

you can check this by checking `if(!Is.PostBack){ }`

Answer (score 0):

My money is on you are re-binding the controls on every postback, instead do this:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{ 
    // Only bind controls on initial page and let viewstate remember what the user did
}
```